When the pullback of a function has finite fiber?
Let $f:X\to Y$ be an injective map of sets, $F(X),F(Y)$ are the set of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on X and Y, respectively.
We have pullback $f^*$ of $f$ defined by
$$
f^*:F(Y)\to F(X), g\mapsto g\circ f
$$
which is a sujective map.
I wonder what condition that $f$ should satisfy such that $(f^*)^{-1}(h)$ is a finite set for all $h\in F(X)$.

What is "the set of functions on $X$" exactly? Do you consider $a : X \to A$ and $b : X \to B$ to be equal if $e : A \simeq B$ and $b = e \circ a$?

@NaïmFavier I actually mean the $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions

Then the fibre is finite if and only if $f$ is a bijection, in which case it has exactly one element ($h \circ f^{-1}$). Otherwise, there is an element $y : Y$ that is not in the image of $f$, so you can tweak the image of this element to get an infinite collection of functions that restrict to $h$ on $X$.

@NaïmFavier Thank you, I believe this is the final answer if there is no other structure on X and Y
